# How this popup loaded?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

in MRP module i found this feature.please tell me where is this function located & where is this button defined.?
(i go through code but unable to find where is the exact location that triggered)

its flow is ADD --> comed popup window to select products -->if selected then those products loaded in  section

[image: popup window with select option]

Comment: it is a html code with some z-index (css-style) greater than the page elements, To know more about z-index read this comprehensive blog http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: thanks AurA:
i mean in OpenERP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a many2many field not a function

```
move_lines': fields.many2many('stock.move', 'mrp_production_move_ids', 'production_id', 'move_id', 'Products to Consume',
            domain=[('state','not in', ('done', 'cancel'))], readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),
```

Comment: thanks u so much..i wasted my time for seek its method :-)
then which function trigger when click 'ADD' button ?

& if u free help me to sortout this issue
http://help.openerp.com/question/8391/how-to-load-child-records-to-fields/

Comment: i have no account on help.openerp.com

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome or firefox to inspect the code elements. Im not sure how you do that in Opera.

try Chrome:

right click -> inspect element -> click on the magnifying glass on the bottom left corner -> select the button, and you can see the HTML it's defined.

Firefox:

right click->inspect element->use the mouse pointer button on the bottom left to click on the button, and get the code.

Both these are really fantastic to find out what you are looking for.